# How to add files to a project?

Tags: ide, qt-creator

I can add headers to the header path but how can I bring in external headers to be available within Qt Creator for editing in project, so they appear in the file list like other headers created from scratch?

In Xcode, you could just drag files into the project, they'd be copied into the project directory and appear in the IDE for editing.

I'd assume you could do this in Qt Creator but I can't find any way to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `qmake - project` from the command line in the directory containing the files and they will generate a `.pro` and you can copy that into a `.pri` and then include the `.pri` in your project, thus allowing you to access and edit the files from within Creator but segregating them nicely should you choose to use those files in other projects as well, but maintaining a single set of build and qmake settings.

Answer (score 8):

Right Click on the project -> Add Existing Files... -> Choose your desired external headers
this way you can edit them (but it is not recommended to edit external headers)

Note: This way, the files will get compiled with your project, so you need to include all dependencies.

Comment: This option does not actually add the files to the creator project file list so you can work with him within the creator like you would other files

Comment: @thuga I have discovered that you must use `qmake -project` to generate a file list that Creator will show.

Comment: What do you do if "Add Existing Files..." is greyed out?  I've tried restarting QtCreator to no avail.

Answer (score 6):

If you add project headers to a target in `CMakeLists.txt`, they'll show up in Qt Creator.

```
file(GLOB HEADERS src/*.hpp src/*.h)
file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.cpp)
add_library(FreenectDriver SHARED ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})
```

[image: qtcreator-cmake]

Answer (score 0):

```
set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        mainwindow.ui
        Class_Neironnaia_Set.h  <---- Add not only to the project but also to CMakeLists.txt write it down. 
)
```